# ASP.NET Web Api 2 Get by Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an `ApiController` as such:

```
public class MessengerController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllMessages()
    {
        // irrelevant code
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetMessage(int index)
    {
        // irrelevant code
    }
}
```

I am trying to call my `GetMessage` function with the following url:

http://localhost:58050/api/messenger/1

But that always calls my `GetAllMessages` function instead. Am I missing something? Here is my `WebApiConfig` class, I haven't changed it from the pregenerated code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your parameter `id`, not `index`, for `GetMessage`.